# How to load data from PostgreSQL to RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm trying to convert data to RichTextBox but still can't do it. Below is my code. My data test and have data, now just read it into RichTextBox.

```
 private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem selectedComune = lvResultCommune.SelectedItems[0];
            string selectedCommuneId = selectedComune.Text;
            if (selectedCommuneId != null)
            {
                NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT ST_AsText(geom) as geometry FROM hanhchinhxa where id_4 = " + selectedCommuneId , conn);
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(data);

                richTextBox.Text = data.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("\n" + "Geometry illegal !!");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Try converting it to a Base 64 string and setting it in the text box, worked for me everytime!

Comment: convert how? @runtimeTerror

Comment: Please do not use string concatenation to create sql commands, you are opening yourself open to Sql Injection attacks.

Comment: Don't worry about that, I'm just experimenting to get results

Comment: `richTextBox.Text = data.ToString();` … isn’t doing what you think it is. `data` is a `DataTable` … it has rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself !

```
richTextBox.Text = data.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).